# How can I add LiveView to an existing Elixir/Phoenix app?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I want to change a form in my existing Phoenix app to use LiveView so I can take advantage of the better image uploading capability described [here](https://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/phoenix-live-view-upload-deep-dive). However the documentation that I've seen only talks about running `mix phx.new my_app --live` to set it up. How can I add it to an existing app instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official installation guide](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/installation.html) is actually mostly about how to add it to an existing Phoenix project (everything except the first paragraph basically):

> If you are using earlier Phoenix versions or your app already exists, keep on reading.